# Any STXXL alternatives to STXXL to handle unknown size at compile time, or any tricks?

Tags: c++, stxxl, large-data

[This question and answers to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136337/is-it-possible-to-define-the-length-of-the-type-to-sort-in-stxxl-at-run-time) reassure me that STXXL handles only fixed data length. Are there any alternatives to STXXL to handle dynamic data size (data size unknown at compile time)?

Or are there any tricks to use STXXL to handle dynamic data size? The above link mentioned defining a number of structures of varying lengths and picking the closest at run-time. I have been considering creating a tool to detect data size or to get the user specified record size, then let the tool automatically generate code using the known size, compile it to another executable, and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a closure to my question.

I did not find an alternative to STXXL to handle unknown record length data. However, the proposal in my question turned out to be working very well for me: creating a tool to detect data size or to get the user specified record size, then let the tool automatically generate code using the known size, compile it to another executable, and run it.

Hope this will help someone in the same situation.